# How to get all .XML files from a specific folder and attached in email and send it in VBA for a specific date (today for example)

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I made a VBA code that gets the last saved file in a folder and send it via Outlook, but I need to get all files from a specific date (from current day) not only the last one.

```
Sub SendEmail_Demo()

  'Declare the variables
  Dim MyPath As String
  Dim MyFile As String
  Dim LatestFile As String
  Dim LatestDate As Date
  Dim LMD As Date
  
'Specify the path to the folder
    MyPath = "..................\XML\"
    
    'Make sure that the path ends in a backslash
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    
    'Get the first XML file from the folder
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xml*", Today(), vbNormal)
    
    'If no files were found, exit the sub
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Loop through each XML file in the folder
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    
        'Assign the date/time of the current file to a variable
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
        
        'If the date/time of the current file is greater than the latest
        'recorded date, assign its filename and date/time to variables
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        
        'Get the next XML file from the folder
        MyFile = Dir
        
    Loop
  
  Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
  
  Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
  Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  
  With OutlookMail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Display
    .HTMLBody = "Hi demo"
    
    .To = "myEmial.com"

    .Subject = "Test demo"
    .Attachments.Add MyPath & LatestFile
    .Send
    
  End With
  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub SendEmail_Demo()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String

    'Specify the path to the folder
    MyPath = "..................\XML\"
    
    'Make sure that the path ends in a backslash
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    
    'Get the first XML file from the folder
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xml", vbNormal)
    
    'If no files were found, exit the sub
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim filesToSend As New Collection
    Dim fileFullName As Variant
    
    Dim startOfToday As Date
    startOfToday = Now() - Timer() / 86400!
    'Timer() ... elapsed seconds since the start of today
    '86400 ..... seconds per day
    
    'Loop through each XML file in the folder
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        fileFullName = MyPath & MyFile
        
        'If the date/time of the current file is greater than
        'today 00:00 then add the file to 'filesToSend collection
        If FileDateTime(fileFullName) > startOfToday Then
            filesToSend.Add fileFullName
        End If
        
        'Get the next XML file from the folder
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
      
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.Mailitem
    
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
    With OutlookMail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = "Hi demo"
        
        .To = "myEmial.com"
        
        .Subject = "Test demo"

        'Attach all the files to one mail
        For Each fileFullName In filesToSend
            .Attachments.Add fileFullName
        Next fileFullName

        .SEND
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Great, it works, but how can I attached in one email all xml files, So now it's work send as many emails as there are files, but I want not to spam. I want to add in one email, all attachments.

Comment: Hi @KonstantinPetkov, oh I misunderstood your question! I updated my answer, please let me know if it works!